# I modified the permissions of /var what have I broken?

Tags: vps, chown, openvz

So I did a dumb thing, I chowned `/var` to a single user and now I am getting errors everywhere,I had to add permissions so that mysql and lighthttpd would start, any easy way to revert changes or must I manually revert changes ?

I am getting errors like `fopen: Permission denied`
 when i run apt-get .

The above error can be fixed by running `sudo chown -R man:root /var/cache/man`

Comment: No way to revert changes, but since it's an OpenVZ VPS, you can simply use `tar -tvf` to quickly overview the permissions in the default official templates available [here](http://wiki.openvz.org/Download/template/precreated) and change yours appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chown it back to root. Then ask the httpd question elsewhere.

Comment: I did that, I want to know I can revert changes to all folders or fix errors as they crop up ?

Comment: change the whole thing back to root ownership:  sudo chown -R /var

Comment: @fabricator4 You probably meant `sudo chown -R root /var`. However, **the whole approach of recursively `chown`ing `/var` back to `root` is a bad idea; a cursory examination of even the top-level contents of `/var` on a healthy system shows that *not everything is owned by root!***

Comment: Yes, you're right on both counts (I meant root:root) however looking at /var, everything is _owned_ by root, it's just that the groups are different: whoopsi, mail, and local, mainly.  Chowning back to root would certainly fix the update problem, but looks like it might be an issue for mail and bug tracker. /var/local may be empty in any case.

Comment: See http://paste.ubuntu.com/1254258/. (it was a few thousand chars too long to paste here).

Comment: @acematrix Thanks, whenevr i get errors, I can see that and figure wat user to add :)